# byte[] vs char[] for AES in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to implement AES in Java (for academic purpose only).

I took default implementation to compare my result with original.

```
private byte[] crypt(int mode, byte[] key, byte[] initializationVector, byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, AES);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);

        cipher.init(mode, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
    catch(BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Where int mode is Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE or Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE.
Note, that key, iv and data are all byte[] (and not char[]).

Now, when I am trying to do my implementation I face problem with Sboxes.
I took array from wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box

In example, there is unsigned char (example is for C++, not for Java).

The problem is: byte in Java is signed (-128 to 127), so half of them is negative, what causes trouble, when I want to use it later as index of array.

If I will convert this sbox to byte[], then I have issue with array's indexes.
If I decide to do everything on char[], then I will double memory usage, plus it will be hard to compare my result with stock implementation (that uses byte[]).

I am sure, that guys who implemented stock encryption were much smarter than me, so I assume byte[] is correct an answer, but how do I handle negative array index in this case?

The only was I see is "sneaky" converting between byte and char when non-negative representation is required, with method like:

```
public class Sbox
{
    // it's array from wiki, 256 elements
    private final char substitute[] =
    {
        0x63, 0x7C, ... 0xBB, 0x16
    };

    public byte substitute(byte index)
    {
        return convert(substitute[convert(index)]);
    }

    private char convert(byte b)
    {
        return (char) (b < 0 ? b + 256 : b);
    }

    private byte convert(char c)
    {
        return (byte) (c < 256 ? c : 256 - c);
    }
}
```

when needed index and back - this isn't most efficient idea, and looks like bug mine.

How it can be done better?
Should it be byte[] or char[] as default structure? (for key/iv/data)
And by the way, just to be certain, cipher.doFinal(data); (in stock implementation) is doing whole encryption, not just the final (non-standard) round?
Does stock implementation utilize AES-NI?

In case it matters: I am outside USA and I have unlocked unlimited crypto power version.

Comment: You need to use `byte[]` in Java. `char[]` is for C or C++ only.

Comment: ok, how to handle negative array index issue?